# Deploying OLD EJBs to Weblogic 12. Desactivate EJB Checker

Tags: deployment, ejb, weblogic

I´m in trouble with old EJBs that i have no control over the source code, there is no source code, only the ejb jar. They were born in weblogic 5.

We are migrating to weblogic 12c and When i deploy then, the EJB checker give me some compliance ejb errors.

I have been investigating the class ...

[Loaded weblogic.ejb.container.compliance.**EJBComplianceChecker** from ......product/Oracle_Home/wlserver/modules/**com.oracle.weblogic.ejb.jar**]

Decompiled and I have found this ....

```
public final class EJBComplianceChecker
  extends BaseComplianceChecker
  implements ComplianceChecker, PlatformConstants
{
  public static final boolean isNeedCheck = Boolean.getBoolean("ignoreEJBChecker");
  static final ComplianceChecker INSTANCE = new EJBComplianceChecker();
  
  public void checkDeploymentInfo(DeploymentInfo di)
    throws ErrorCollectionException
  {
    if (isNeedCheck) {
      return;
    }
    Set<Class<?>> deploymentInfoCheckers = new HashSet();
    Object interceptorChecker = null;
    Object[] relationshipCheckers = null;
    for (BeanInfo bi : di.getBeanInfos()) ....
```

I think this might be some kind of deployment configuration, but i have found no information about it...

```
public static final boolean isNeedCheck = Boolean.getBoolean("ignoreEJBChecker");
```

it controls the value and let it check or not.

```
if (isNeedCheck) {
          return;
        }
```

thanks

Comment: Boolean.getBoolean() reads the value from the system proroerty then you can try to set the system property in the server's command line : 
-DignoreEJBChecker=true

Answer (score 0):

that seems to work. Know i can not see the error.

Thank for all Emmanuel